# How to set WebView2 settings on blazor with wpf

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, razor

I'm creating an app made in blazor and wpf, I would like to know how I can set the WebView2 settings.

I use **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Wpf** packages

My **XAML** file has the following code:

```
<wv:BlazorWebView HostPage="wwwroot/index.html" Services="{StaticResource services}">
     <wv:BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
          <wv:RootComponent Selector="#app" ComponentType="{x:Type local:main}" />
     </wv:BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
</wv:BlazorWebView>
```

In **C#** code I have the following:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.WebView2;

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly ICoreWebView2Wrapper _WebView;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        var blazorCollection = new ServiceCollection();
        blazorCollection.AddBlazorWebView();
        Resources.Add("services", blazorCollection.BuildServiceProvider());
        InitializeComponent();
        Initialize();
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        _WebView.Settings.IsZoomControlEnabled = false;
        _WebView.Settings.AreDevToolsEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

I get **CS0649** on compilation for `private readonly ICoreWebView2Wrapper _WebView;`

When I tried to compile and I try to open the application I get exception

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Someone who has already added these WebView2 settings can tell me how to use them correctly.

Comment: I have the exact same question. Any luck?

Answer (score 1):

Add a reference to your WebView2 in your xaml:

`<blazor:BlazorWebView HostPage="wwwroot\index.html" Services="{StaticResource Services}" x:Name="blazorWebView1">`

In stead of calling your Initialize() do:
`Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;`

```
private async void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      await blazorWebView1.WebView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
      blazorWebView1.WebView.CoreWebView2.Settings.IsZoomControlEnabled = false;
}
```